# IIS hosting WCF HttpBinding only

Tags: wcf, iis, basichttpbinding

I am confused as to what binding IIS can support for WCF.

I have read in some learning materials that it can only support basicHttpBinding but I have seen Silverlight demos where NetTCPBinding has been supported?

Any clarification on this matter is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of IIS.  You can use most bindings with IIS 7, just make sure the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) feature is installed if you want to use non-HTTP bindings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx

If you're using an earlier version of IIS then you can only use the HTTP-based bindings.

Comment: Adding to Matt's reference, see [Extend Your WCF Services Beyond HTTP With WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx), MSDN Magazine, September 2007.